How to execute locally isntalled program on a remote cluster
I'm new to networking so any help is appreciated.
I have a program installed at C:/user/my_program.exe
I have access to a SLURM-based remote cluster on which I can run commands like sbatch, sinfo, etc.
One command involves
sbatch --export=FLROOT=${CUSTOM_INSTALL_PATH}, where CUSTOM_INSTALL_PATH is supposed to be my local directory C:/user/my_program.exe
That is, I need to make a local program executable on a cluster.
How can I do that?
I don't have a shared network.
I'm aware that I can use commands like scp to just copy stuff from the local directory to the remote, is that enough to make it executable?
Thanks
